# Using a custom filter button to filter a list, works on first click but subsequent clicks don't work as well! SPFX

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I have 2 SP lists (A and B).
List A has filter buttons next to each list item. When a user clicks a button it should filter List B, only showing the related items.

List A has an Id column which List B matches *it's* column (MasterItems) with List A's Id.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
public _getListItems() {
    sp.web.lists.getByTitle("ListA").items.get().then((items: any[]) => {
      let returnedItems: IListAItem[] = items.map((item) => { return new ListAItem(item); });

      this.setState({ 
        Items: returnedItems,
        ListAItems: returnedItems,

      });
    });
    sp.web.lists.getByTitle("ListB").items.get().then((items: any[]) => { 
      let returnedItems: IListBItem[] = items.map((item) => { return new ListBItem(item); });

      this.setState({ 

        ListBItems: returnedItems, //This brings in the items from ListB so they can be filtered on this.state.ListB when clicked
      });
    }); 
  }
  private _editItem = (ev: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
   this._getListItems(); //This attempts to reset the list when another filter is clicked, but is half working!
    const sid = Number(ev.currentTarget.id);
    const sid2 = 'DIBR'+sid;
    let _item = this.state.ListBItems.filter((item) => { return item.MasterItem == sid2; });

    if (_item && _item.length > 0) {

      sp.web.lists.getByTitle("ListB").items.get().then((items: any[]) => {
        let returnedItems: IListBItem[] = 
            items.filter(i => _item.some(other => other.Id === i.Id)).map(
              (item) => new ListBItem(item)
              );

        this.setState({ 
          ListBItems: returnedItems,
         });
      });
     } 
  }
```

The problem is that when the button is clicked next to an item, it filters correctly on first click!
but if filtered again on the same or different item it will sometimes unset the filter and mix results, other times it will filter correctly. So I'm suspecting I've made a state problem here, but can't seem to discover why.

Regards,

T

UPDATE: I've added a clear filter button which makes things work, but would like the user to be able to click on filter to filter instead of having to clear it each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing the same in my SharePoint list
so basically I always set the clear filter function before the filter function,
for example:

```
function myFilter(){
//my filter code goes here
}

function clearFilter(){
//the clear filter code goes here
}
```

lets say you are running the function on an item select or a button click or text input change, set the clear filter to run before the filter.

```
function funcGroup{
clearFilter();

setTimeout(() => {
    myFilter();  
}, 300);

}
```

or

```
function funcGroup{
setTimeout(() => {
clearFilter();
}, 300);

    myFilter();  
}
```

I am using this scenario with my SharePoint lists and its working perfect...

Comment: Yeah I tried that but it doesn't clear it in time if you know what I mean, it's giving me weird results. I'll continue to test it and come back here.

Comment: try to set a time out to either one of the actions, if that could help a bit to delay actions just to give time for the list to go to a steady state, I don't know what is your list scenario but sometimes I play with setTimeout to delay an action waiting for my info get collected or cleared..